# awk next and pattern match

Tags: bash, awk

If we have the following csv files, we only want to get the $9 in the "DELTA Energy Terns" part, excluding the line starting with "Frame"

```
Ligand Energy Terms
Frame #,VDWAALS,EEL,EGB,ESURF,ESCF,G gas,G solv,TOTAL
0,0.0,0.0,-37.2465,2.70257904,98.8916,0.0,-34.54392096,64.34767904
1,0.0,0.0,-33.1958,2.71419624,80.6403,0.0,-30.48160376,50.15869624

DELTA Energy Terms
Frame #,VDWAALS,EEL,EGB,ESURF,ESCF,DELTA G gas,DELTA G solv,DELTA TOTAL
0,-43.3713,0.0,44.4036,-5.24443392,-27.4605,-43.3713,39.15916608,-31.67263392
1,-43.7597,0.0,37.343,-5.1764544,-23.3471,-43.7597,32.1665456,-34.9402544
2,-42.5618,0.0,44.0748,-5.2738956,-26.6719,-42.5618,38.8009044,-30.4327956
3,-43.1034,0.0,41.3681,-5.25029544,-27.1501,-43.1034,36.11780456,-34.13569544
```

Desired output:

```
-31.6726
-34.9402
-30.4327
-34.1356
```

The following attempts will print out all the $9, including $9 in the "Ligand Energy Terms" part.

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /DELTA Energy Terms/ {next} $1 ~ /Frame/ {next} {printf("%24.4f\n",$9)}'

awk -F, '$1 ~ /DELTA Energy Terms/ {next}  {printf("%24.4f\n",$9)}'
```

Could any guru enlighten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick

```
awk -F, '/^DELTA/ {capture=1} /Energy Terms$/ {next} /^Frame/ {next} (capture) {print $9}'
```

I use a `capture` flag to control whether individual records should be captured.  By default `capture` is zero.  When the `DELTA Energy Terms` line is parsed, I start capturing.  I skip any rows that end in `Energy Terms` or start with `Frame`.  Otherwise, if we are "capturing", then I bring out the ninth element.

If you are using this script regularly, I recommend using something like the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}
/^DELTA Energy Terms/ {
    capture = 1;
    next
}
/Energy Terms$/ {
    capture = 0;
    next
}
/^Frame/ { next }
(capture) { print $9 }
```

Save the script as `extract-delta` and make it executable, then you can use it just like any other shell command:

```
$ cat input-file | tr -d '\015' | ./extract-delta
-31.67263392
-34.9402544
-30.4327956
-34.13569544
```

Comment: This one works almost perfectly! If we do "awk -F, '/^DELTA/ {capture=1} /Energy Terms$/ {next} /^Frame/ {next} (capture) {print $9}' input > check.dat"   There will be trailing (^M) at the end of each line.  May I know any reason behind this?

Comment: That is usually caused by having DOS style end of line characters (`\r\n`). `\r` translates to Ctrl+M and `\n` to Ctrl+J.  You can filter the input through `tr -d '\015'` to remove carriage return characters.

Comment: Thanks!  May I know if there is any awk manual for "capture"? I couldn't find any after the search.  It looks quite powerful and would love to dig more into it.

Comment: `capture` is simply a variable that enables the `{print $9}` action for a section of the input.

Comment: Hi D. Shawley, may i know why the bracket {capture=1} and (capture) are different?  Is there any terminology for this "capture flag" technique?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below awk command.

```
$ awk -v RS="\n\n" -v FS="\n" '/^DELTA Energy Terms/{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){split($i, a, /,/);print a[9]}}' RS=  file
-31.67263392
-34.9402544
-30.4327956
-34.13569544
```

- `RS="\n\n"`, so a blank line is set to Record Separator.
- `FS="\n"`, a newline character is set to Field Separator.
- `/^DELTA Energy Terms/` If a Record starts with `^DELTA Energy Terms` then do the following operation on that particular record.
- `{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){split($i, a, /,/);print a[9]}}` iterate over all the fields except for 1 and 2 and then split each field according to the comma, then store the spitted items into an array named `a` .
- `print a[9]` prints the element at 9th index in the associative array `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this with bash, using the following:

```bash
tail -n +$((2 + $(grep -n "DELTA Energy Terms" input.txt | cut -d":" -f1) )) input.txt | cut -d"," -f9
```

The `tail -n +$((2 + $(grep -n "DELTA Energy Terms" input.txt` part will print the lines of the input file starting at the line that contains *DELTA Energy Terms* plus 2, then `cut` will give you the 9th field that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

All these solutions work, so solved the immediate problem, but none answered the implied question.

To review the command in question, why doesn't this work?

```
'$1 ~ /DELTA Energy Terms/ {next} $1 ~ /Frame/ {next} {printf("%24.4f\n",$9)}
```

Let's break it down.

```
# Skip every line where the first field matches. 
$1 ~ /DELTA Energy Terms/ {next} 
  # No line matches this criteria, so this has no effect. 
  # Explanation: The field separator isn't set, so defaults to breaking fields on white space. 
  # If you print out the first field, you will see "DELTA" on this line, not "DELTA Energy Terms".

# Skip every line where the first field matches "Frame". 
$1 ~ /Frame/ {next} 
  # This matches and gets skipped.

# Print every line that didn't get skipped.
{printf("%24.4f\n",$9)}
  # The two "Energy Terms" title lines don't have any entries in field 9, 
  # so it prints blanks for those lines.
```